# transform columns from column list within select method that's attached to join method

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two data frames with the same schema. I'm using the outer join method on both data frames and I'm using the select and coalesce methods to select and transform all columns. I want to iterate over the column list within the select method without explicitly defining each column within the coalesce method. It would be great to know if there's a solution without using a UDF. The two tables that are being joined are `songs` and `staging_songs`  within the code snippets below.

Instead of explicitly defining each column like so:

```
updated_songs = songs.join(staging_songs, songs.song_id == staging_songs.song_id, how='full').select(
    f.coalesce(staging_songs.song_id, songs.song_id),
    f.coalesce(staging_songs.artist_name, songs.artist_name),
    f.coalesce(staging_songs.song_name, songs.song_name)
)
```

Doing something along the lines of:

```
# column names to iterate over in select method
songs_columns = songs.columns

updated_songs = songs.join(staging_songs, songs.song_id == staging_songs.song_id, how='full').select(
            #using for loop like this raises a syntax error
            for col in songs_columns:
                f.coalesce(staging_songs.col, songs.col))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
updated_songs = songs.join(staging_songs, songs["song_id"] == staging_songs["song_id"], how='full').select(*[f.coalesce(staging_songs[col], songs[col]).alias(col) for col in songs_columns])
```